# Example of strict inclusion for the localization of associated primes

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M$ an $A$-module. It is well known that
$$\operatorname{Ass} M\cap\operatorname{Spec}S^{-1}A\subset\operatorname{Ass}S^{-1}M,$$
and that equality holds if $A$ (or $M$) is Noetherian. Presumably strict inclusion is possible if $A$ is not Noetherian, but I couldn't think of an example (I couldn't find any reference mentioning this, either.) So naturally I turn to my trustworthy math stack exchange.

Comment: You are right; I took the liberty of abusing notation and considered $\operatorname{Spec}S^{-1}A$ to be a subset of $\operatorname{Spec}A$.

Comment: A reference is Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Chapter 4, exercise 1(c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb F_2^{\mathbb N}$ be a countable direct product of copies of the field with two elements. This is a von Neumann regular ring and thus $\operatorname{Ann}(a)$ is principal generated by an idempotent for all $a\in R$. If $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ containing the ideal $\mathbb F_2^{(\mathbb N)}$, then $P$ is not associated. Otherwise, $P=Re$ with $e\in R$. Since $\mathbb F_2^{(\mathbb N)}\subseteq P$ we get $e=1$, a contradiction. Set $S=R-P$. Then $\operatorname{Ass}R\cap\operatorname{Spec}S^{-1}R=\emptyset$. On the other hand, $S^{-1}R$ is a field, and thus $\operatorname{Ass}S^{-1}R\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: What did you mean by the parentheses in the notation $\mathbb{F}_2^{(\mathbb{N})}$ ?

Comment: Direct sum of countable many copies of $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm having two issues: 1.Why does $\mathbb{F}_2^{(\mathbb{N})}\subset P$ imply $e=1$? 2.Why does $\operatorname{Spec}R/\mathbb{F}_2\cap\operatorname{Ass}R=\varnothing$ imply $\operatorname{Ass}R\cap\operatorname{Spec}S^{-1}R=\varnothing$?

Comment: 1) Every element which has $1$ in one place and $0$ elsewhere must be in $Re$, so $e$ has $1$ everywhere; 2) I don't understand what you mean by the first equality, but I've thought like this: any associated prime of $R$ disjoint from $S$ must be contained in $P$. Since any prime is maximal in a VNR ring, then such an associated prime should coincide with $P$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\operatorname{Spec}R/\mathbb{F}_2^{(\mathbb{N})}\cap\operatorname{Ass}R= \varnothing$ for the first equality. I reviewed your answer more carefully, and I agree it is a correct answer!